# Count total number of pages a single wordpress id has been split with <!--nextpage-->

Tags: php, wordpress, function

How can I count total number of pages a wordpress post or page has been split into multiple pages using the following:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

I can easily get current page number with:

```
$pagenumber = get_query_var( 'page', 1 );
```

But, how do I get the total count?

Answer (score -1):

As the source post describes:

You can use a plugin or I would prefer the manual code way.

```
<?php
echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
?>
```

Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-count/

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-number-of-post?replies=4

Comment: This returns total number of posts... I already mentioned there is only one post, I just want to return how many times this single post has been split into "page 2", "page 3" ... etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
'mid_size' => 2,
'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
) ); ?>
```

Comment: This function returns post pagination with links, I just want to return an integer, which equals the amount of times the post has been split.